# What approach is to be used in these type of questions? Is there a standard method or just pure logic?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solution of the differential equation
> $$\left\{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{y^2}{(x-y)^2}\right\}\mathrm{d}x+\left\{\frac{x^2}{(x-y)^2}-\frac{1}{y}\right\}\mathrm{d}y=0$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks! Will do so.

Comment: Two methods: (1) Checking whether the equation is exact, (2) if it's not exact, finding an integrating factor that makes it exact. They should be done in order, 1st is trivially easy, 2nd might require ingenuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left\{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{y^2}{(x-y)^2}\right\}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left\{\frac{x^2}{(x-y)^2}-\frac{1}{y}\right\}$, this differential equation is exact.

We want to find the solution: $F=F(x,y)=0$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}&=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{y^2}{(x-y)^2}~~~(1)\\ 
\\
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}&=\frac{x^2}{(x-y)^2}-\frac{1}{y}~~~(2)
\end{align}$$

Integrate $(1)$

$$F=\int \frac{1}{x}-\frac{y^2}{(x-y)^2}dx=\ln|x|+\frac{y^2}{x-y}+g(y)~~~(3)$$

Plug into $(2)$

$$\begin{align}
\frac{2xy-y^2}{(x-y)^2}+g'(y)&=\frac{x^2}{(x-y)^2}-\frac{1}{y}\\
\\
g'(y)&=\frac{x^2-2xy+y^2}{(x-y)^2}-\frac{1}{y}=1-\frac{1}{y}\\
\\
g(y)&=\int 1-\frac{1}{y} ~dy=y-\ln|y|+C~~~(4)
\end{align}$$

Combine $(3)(4)$,

$$\ln|x|+\frac{y^2}{x-y}+y-\ln|y|+C=0$$

Further simplify it, we get the solution:

$$\ln|x|+\frac{xy}{x-y}-\ln|y|+C=0$$

Comment: Here's a little note you might read, on [enforcing quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).